# How to symbolize this "only" statement in first-order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm having trouble symbolizing this sentence:

"Every giraffe loves only Alfred."

My thought process was "Every x such that x is a giraffe then it loves something y and y is Alfred."

∀x (Gx → ∃y (L(xy) ∧ y=a))

According to the program I am using, this is incorrect, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe $∀x (Gx → L(xa ) ∧ ∀y (L(xy) → y=a)))$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that $\exists y(L(xy)\wedge y=a)$ just means that $L(xy)\wedge y=a$ is true for *some* value of $y$.  The only possible value of $y$ that could make it true is $y=a$, so this just says "$x$ loves Alfred" and says nothing about whether $x$ loves anything else.  (In other words, $\exists y(L(xy)\wedge y=a)$ is just equivalent to $L(xa)$.)

To express the meaning of "only", you have to break down what "loves only Alfred" really means.  If I love only Alfred, that is really two separate statements combined: first, I love Alfred, and second, I don't love anything other than Alfred.  Your formula $\exists y(L(xy)\wedge y=a)$ (or $L(xa)$) captures the first statement, but not the second.  So, you just have to combine your formula with another one that says $x$ does not love anything other than Alfred.

Comment: (L(xa) ∧ ∼∃y (L(xy) ∧ ∼y=a)) was what I got. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Yep, that would work!